# How to use REST API to add a VM role?

Tags: azure

How to use REST API to add a VM role?

I can't use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157184.aspx to delete a VM. Do I need some other steps for that?

And also I want to get some code for adding a VM Role to existed VM Role service.

Comment: Can you what *you* have done?

Comment: And why you think you can't use the referred action to delete role? What code are you using? What is the request you are executing, and what response do you get back?

Comment: Isn't this three completely separate questions? It may help to split these up, and like the folks above have mentioned, include what you have tried and the results for each.

Comment: Your use of the term "VM Role" is in contradiction to the link you provided.  "VM Role" refers to the stateless VM that was introduced by Microsoft over a year ago.  The link you provided is not relevant to VM Role; it is relevant to the newer persistent VM, known as Windows Azure VM.  To add a vm to an existing deployment, use "Add Role".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157186.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Autoscaling will solve all of your problems here.  Check out [this guide](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/autoscaling/) to get you started.

With autoscaling, you can set up rules to add/remove instances on a deployment based on certain events or constraints.  This can run on-premise or on a separate worker role.  If you use WASABi, then you won't have to mess with making the role management API calls yourself.

I hope this helps, if you have any specific questions just ask and I will do my best to answer them.

I have also posed a few errors I have encountered and the solutions for them on my [blog](http://robertgreiner.com).

Comment: WASABI is not relevant to the Persistent VM, which I believe to be the VM of interest to the original questioner.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so to until the OP started talking about Roles at the end of the question.  Once we get some clarification I can update my answer.